# Convert String to array in thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have a String variable like

```
scope="settings,locations,accounts,notifications"
```

And I want to convert in an array, how it can be done in thymeleaf?

Comment: This is how you can do it. `scope.split(',');`